# React / Redux Async not waiting for returned response

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

First of all my code **is** working (everything  is exported correctly etc ) but it's not waiting for the async return of data.
I'm using *redux-thunk* for my async middleware

I have an action named *async.js*

```
export function itemsHasErrored(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED',
        hasErrored: bool
    };
}

export function itemsIsLoading(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_IS_LOADING',
        isLoading: bool
    };
}

export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(items) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
        items
    };
}

export function itemsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));

        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((items) => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

My reducer

```
export function itemsHasErrored(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED':
            return action.hasErrored;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function itemsIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_IS_LOADING':
            return action.isLoading;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function items(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I have a container component, *asyncContainer.js*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {itemsFetchData} from '../../../actions/async';
import AsyncUI from './asyncUI'

class AsyncContainer extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('http://5826ed963900d612000138bd.mockapi.io/items');
    }

    render() {

        if (this.props.hasErrored) {
            return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }

        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading…</p>;
        }
//This fails to wait
        return (
               <AsyncUI />
        );
    }
}

AsyncContainer.propTypes = {
    fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items,
        hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AsyncContainer);
```

And finally I have a simple UI component named *asyncUI.js* written in a functional way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const AsyncUI = (items) => {

    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.id}>
                    {item.label}
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AsyncUI);
```

In *asyncContainer.js* you can see the call to my simple UI component

```
 return (
               <AsyncUI />
        );
```

But on calling the property of the redux store  *items* in  *asyncUI.js* an empty array, therefore the `items.map` fails

**However**, if I remove the code from *asyncUI.js* and place it in *asyncContainer.js* it works

*This is the code that works* in *asyncContainer.js*

```
  class AsyncContainer extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.fetchData('http://5826ed963900d612000138bd.mockapi.io/items');
        }

        render() {
            if (this.props.hasErrored) {
                return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
            }

            if (this.props.isLoading) {
                return <p>Loading…</p>;
            }

//THIS IS WHERE I HAD <Async />
            return (
                <ul>
                    {this.props.items.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.id}>
                            {item.label}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            );
        }
    }

    AsyncContainer.propTypes = {
        fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            items: state.items,
            hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
            isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
        };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
        };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AsyncContainer);
```

I think the problem is that the component  is rendering before the items data is ready. This is normal react behavior. So how do I "hold off" the rendering. As you can see I'm trying to use a Container /Component style of architecture. I can always use the solution that works as mentioned above, but I'd like to stick with this Container /Component.
Am I going to have to delve deeper into Promises etc ?
Should I not use the functional way of writing for asyncUI.js ?
I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
const AsyncUI = ({items}) => {
              /* ^ see ^ */
    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.id}>
                    {item.label}
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    ); }
```

This pulls the `items` value off the props you reacted in the `mapStateToProps` function, which is an object, not an array (hence no `map` function).

**NOTE:** This should fix your issue, but it is still *technically* trying to render the items before they are ready in 2 instances:

1. The first time the component renders.  The initial state for `itemsIsLoading` is `false`, so the first render will fail all the safety checks.  The default value for `items` is `[]` so it should just render `<ul></ul>` for a very brief moment until the `itemsIsLoading(true)` action is dispatched.  You can set the initial state to `true` for stop this, or change the loading check to be

   ```
   if (this.props.isLoading || this.props.items.length != 0) {
       return <p>Loading…</p>;
   }
   ```

   An argument can be made for how necessary either of those solutions actually are.
2. After the `fetch` returns the order the actions is dispatched in will result in another brief render of `<ul></ul>` as the loading state is set to `false` before the items are set.  See [dgrijuela's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43539677/6902543) for one way to fix this.  Another way would be to not dispatch seperate actions and have the `ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS` and `ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED` actions also change the `itemsIsLoading` value back to false (multiple reducers can act on the same action type).

Comment: Hi, thanks, YES this works, such a simple mistake i made. I've upped your answer, cheers

Comment: opps, I forgot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You call `dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false))` before `dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items))`

Try like this:

```
// async.js
...

export function itemsFetchData(url) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));

    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }

            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((items) => {
          dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items));
          dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));
        })
        .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

Comment: Not working, exactly the same. asyncUI is rendering before the data (items) is ready

Comment: Your answer is correct to a degree but I also need the answer from Micheal Peyper as well

Answer (score 0):

see Michael Peyper for a good answer

It turns out that the problem was with the functional style of coding of my *asyncUI* component. I converted it back to the 'standard' stateful component and bingo it worked.

asyncContainer.js

```
class AsyncContainer extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('http://5826ed963900d612000138bd.mockapi.io/items');
    }

    render() {

          if (this.props.hasErrored) {
                  return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
              }

              if (this.props.isLoading) {
                  return <p>Loading…</p>;
              }
              return (
                  <AsyncUI />     
        )

    }
}
```

*asyncUI.js*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

    class AsyncUI extends Component {

        render() {
                return (
                <ul>
                {this.props.items.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.label}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>   
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            items: state.items,
        };
    };

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AsyncUI);
```

Hope this helps anyone :-)